# Maximum number of cookies allowed

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

As far as Google searches tell me, the maximum allowed number of cookies depends very much on the browser, however I cannot find any recent data as to how much cookies are allowed on modern browsers.

I need to store a somewhat large number of user preferences in cookies (for not-yet-registered users), so what would be the best way of doing that? (Also, those cookies would be accessed both via javascript client-side and php server-side)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the [rfc](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt):

- at least 300 cookies
- at least 4096 bytes per cookie (as measured by the size of the
      characters that comprise the cookie non-terminal in the syntax
      description of the Set-Cookie header)
- at least 20 cookies per unique host or domain name

Those are minimum requirements. The IE6 team didn't get that. Everything else is highly browser-specific. You'd better write a test-platform to test each browser. Test the maximum size and number with little incremental steps (and check if they still are readable).

Also, I seem to remember apache has a problem with huges numbers of cookies. Can't remember where i've seen that though.

Here is a little cookie-testing script:
http://krijnhoetmer.nl/stuff/javascript/maximum-cookies/

Comment: From that rfc, and the same section quoted above, the last paragraph says: 'Applications should use as few and as small cookies as possible, and they should cope gracefully with the loss of a cookie.' That may be better advice than worrying about banging up against user agent limits.

Comment: When you say "20 cookies per unique host", do you mean 20 shared throughout **all** sub-domains or 20 per sub-domain?

Comment: @Berzemus, Gosh I wanted to +1 the above comment but realized that was written by me... Does your "20 cookies per unique host" mean 20 per sub-domain or 20 total?

Comment: Reading the RFC, it's hard to be certain, as domains can be matched (a.b.com matches .b.com, but not b.com, etc.). Not sure how that impacts the "20 cookies per domain" rule, nor how the different browsers implement that rule.

Answer (score 16):

The best way would be to not store them in a cookie at all.

Store them in a database, and store the DB key in the cookie.  If it's just a few preferences then security isn't much of an issue.

Don't forget that cookies will be sent with every request - if you have 2kb of cookie data and load 10 images on a page, that's an extra 22kb of data.

Comment: They are stored in the database as well, however, we're assuming there will be a large enough number of visitors, so I feel sort of queasy about thrashing the database for, say, 20 to 50 values on every page request. Cookies would take at least some part of the load away.

Comment: You only need to pull them out of the database for the first hit then put them into the session.

Answer (score 6):

Number of Cookies:

- Chrome 9 allowed 180 cookies per domain
- Firefox 3.6.3 allowed 50 cookies per domain
- Internet Explorer 8 allowed 50 cookies per domain
- Opera 10 and 9 allowed 30 cookies per domain

Cookie size Limits (4096 bytes):

- Firefox and Safari allow cookies with up to 4097 characters, that’s 4096 for the name and value and one for the equals sign.
- Opera allows cookies with up to 4096 characters, which is for the name, value, and equals sign.
- Internet Explorer allows cookies with up to 4095 characters, which is for the name, value and, equals sign.

SRC: http://webdesign.about.com/od/cookies/f/cookies-per-domain-limit.htm and http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2008/05/17/browser-cookie-restrictions/

Answer (score 4):

I looked into this today, if you want to support most browsers, then don't exceed 50 cookies per domain, and don't exceed 4095 bytes per domain (i.e. total size of all cookies <= 4095 bytes)

To read more about it, [here is the test page and results](http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/).

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, it's 20 for the majority general, more for some, and 10 for one particular browser (again IIRC, IE5.5?). Up to 10 is considered a safe number.

You don't really need more than one anyway - just use one to store an ID client-side and store everything you need stored server-side against that same ID. Apart from anything else, the less data you leave the the client, the less there is for them to remove/corrupt/hack/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much sense it makes from their point of view, but [I've seen websites in the wild](http://webcookies.info/number-of-cookies/) that were setting over 450 cookies and [reporting to over 140 distinctive third party domains](http://webcookies.info/third-party-domains/).