# How many cookies can we have for a domain?

Tags: cookies

I know that there is a limit on how much data can a cookie hold, but is there a limit on how many cookies can we set?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283774/maximum-number-of-cookies-allowed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt

> Practical user agent
>   implementations have limits on the
>   number and    size of cookies that
>   they can store.  In general, user
>   agents' cookie    support should have
>   no fixed limits.  They should strive
>   to store as    many frequently-used
>   cookies as possible.  Furthermore,
>   general-use    user agents should
>   provide each of the following minimum
>   capabilities    individually, although
>   not necessarily simultaneously:
>
> ```
>   * at least 300 cookies
>
>   * at least 4096 bytes per cookie (as measured by the size of the
>     characters that comprise the cookie non-terminal in the syntax
>     description of the Set-Cookie header)
>
>   * at least 20 cookies per unique host or domain name
> ```

Answer (score 10):

Based on my own research, I suggest that you do not exceed **50 cookies per domain**, and **4095 bytes per domain**. That is, the size of all the cookies on your domain should not exceed 4095 bytes.

If you want to read more, I have shared my research [here](http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/).

Comment: Looks like the link is dead. Anybody have an update?

Comment: @ChipTol Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

I've seen websites in the wild that were setting over 450 cookies and [reporting to over 140 distinctive third party domains](http://webcookies.info/third-party-domains/).